# Adding 'click' event listener using 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<li>Facebook</li>
<li>Twitter</li>
<li>Souncloud</li>
```

JS:

```
var links = ['https://www.facebook.com/', 'https://twitter.com', 'https://soundcloud.com'];

function openURL (url) {
    location.href = url;
}

window.onload = function () {

    var listElement = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (i=0;i<listElement.length;i++) {
        listElement[i].addEventListener('click',openURL(links[i]))
    }

}
```

I want the code to work in such a way that when the user clicks either of the list elements, it opens up the respective website. For certain reasons I do NOT want to use the `<a>` tag.

The logic to the code is very simple. First, a variable is created which returns an array of all the `<li>` tags in the document. Then using the 'for' loop, I set an event listener to each of the `<li>` tags in the array. The function I run simply opens the website.

Somehow, whenever I open the page, it gets redirected automatically, without clicking, to facebook.com. Why does this happen??

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because your event handler will be called later (by user action), and that time, `i` isn't what you want. You have to use **closure** to keep it internal.

```js
var links = ['https://www.facebook.com/', 'https://twitter.com', 'https://soundcloud.com'];

function openURL(link) {
  console.log(link);
};


window.onload = function () {

    var listElement = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (i=0;i<listElement.length;i++) {
        listElement[i].addEventListener('click',(function (i) {
          return function () {
            openURL(links[i]);
          };
        }(i)));
    }

}
```

```html
<li>Facebook</li>
<li>Twitter</li>
<li>Souncloud</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Could you explain to me what the `(i)` in the third last line of the code is for? I can't understand the use...

Comment: @MihirChaturvedi In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/3971911), you can find complete explanation.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `click',openURL(links[i])`, it will call `openUrl`. You should use `.bind(context, params)`. Also note, first argument of eventListener is `event`

Also, `window.onload = function` is considered as bad practice as it will override any previous listener. You should use `.addEventListener`

```js
var links = ['https://www.facebook.com/', 'https://twitter.com', 'https://soundcloud.com'];

function openURL(event, url) {
  //location.href = url;
  console.log(url)
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var listElement = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (i = 0; i < listElement.length; i++) {
    listElement[i].addEventListener('click', openURL.bind(null, event, links[i]))
  }
})
```

```html
<li>Facebook</li>
<li>Twitter</li>
<li>Souncloud</li>
```